# HTML Anchor Plus Javascript Scroll

Tags: javascript, html

I’m having a terrible time coding what should be a very simple sequence. When I click on “Go to Section 2”, I want it to go to the Anchor and then scroll vertically a given amount (50px here). So, what happens is, it puts the anchor at the page top, but it does not perform the additional adjustment scroll. In order to see this, you have to fill the two paragraph blocks with a lot of text.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function scrollxy(dx,dy) { 
                window.scrollBy(dx,dy); 
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><a href="#anchor2" onClick="scrollxy(0,-50);">Go to Section 2</a></p>
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
        <p>Lots of text ...</p>
        <a id="anchor2"></a> 
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
        <p>Lots of text ...</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using a timeout for the "scrollxy" function... what's probably happening is it's doing both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `onClick` function is being called before anchor scroll down. You have to dalay the script execution in order to put it to work:

```
       function scrollxy(dx,dy) { 
            setTimeout(function() {
               window.scrollBy(dx,dy);
            }, 10);
        }
```

And

```
    <p><a href="#anchor2" onClick="scrollxy(0,50);">Go to Section 2</a></p>
```

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5d34whzn/1/)

Comment: Thank you, Nanndoj! Adding the 10ms time delay solves the problem. However, I have one question for you: Why does the function definition have to be inside the setTimeout definition.  Why doesn’t the scroll function work when I write it as below, which is intuitively and conceptually cleaner?

function scrollxy(dx,dy) {
 window.scrollBy(dx,dy);
 window.setTimeout("scrollxy()", 10)
}

Comment: Example: Imagine scroll is at position 0 and the anchor is at 500. click function `scrollxy` will be executed first  (go to position 50) then the browser will execute the default anchor behavior (go to anchor position 500). When we delay the execution with `setTimeout` the default browser behavior will be executed (go to position 500) and then `scrolxy` will be called later (go to position 550)

Comment: I guess this fiddle answers the question in your comment http://jsfiddle.net/j9xy5v1g/